# If ZFC is inconsistent, does it follow that Rayo's number is not well defined?

Tags: set-theory, definition

Rayo's number was defined as "The smallest number bigger than any finite number named by an expression in the language of set theory with a googol symbols or less.". It's not clear to me what they mean by set theory, i'll assume it's ZFC. My question is: what if ZFC is inconsistent? Would Rayo's number then not exist? Or would it still exist?

Comment: If $\mathsf {ZFC}$ is *inconsistent* it proves everything; thus, also the existence of a square triangle.

Comment: Did you read the Wikipedia article [Rayo's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayo%27s_number)?